# Sketch won't open safe in homework game assignment

Tags: function, events, p5.js

Im not sure I understood the assigment correctly.
I tried to insert my code in the space designated for it, but still the sketch does not makes open the safe. not sure what to do. any suggestion is wellcome.I would like to know where Im doing it wrong
Here is the challenge I struggle with:

District Attorney Torvalds is well respected in Console City as an upstanding citizen and
enforcer of the law. Of course he’s as crooked as they come. I’ve had enough of having our
hard work at Sleuth and Co undermined by his bribes and back-payments. Let’s take take this
sucker down. I happen to know that Torvalds keeps his incriminating documents spread amongst
several safes in town. I’ll need you to bend the rules a little by breaking into them and
retrieving the incriminating evidence.

The first safe is in Torvald’s office. Crack it by doing the following:

```
When any key is pressed:
- Make secureStorageComb_0 equal to 15

When any key is released:
- Make secureStorageComb_0 equal to 41

When the mouse button is released:
- Make secureStorageComb_0 equal to 6

When the mouse button is pressed:
- Make secureStorageComb_0 equal to 14

Whilst the mouse is being dragged:
- Make secureStorageComb_1 equal to 54

When the mouse button is pressed:
- Make secureStorageComb_1 equal to 34

When the mouse button is released:
- Make secureStorageComb_1 equal to 77
```

There are many possible ways of investigating this case, but you
should use ONLY the following commands:

```
- The assignment operator aka. the equals sign !
```

```js
//declare the variables

var secureStorageComb_0;
var secureStorageComb_1;


function preload()
{
    //IMAGES WILL BE LOADED HERE
}

function setup()
{
    createCanvas(512,512);

    //initialise the variables
    secureStorageComb_0 = 0;
    secureStorageComb_1 = 0;
}

///////////////////EVENT HANDLERS///////////////////

//Add your code to these events to open the safe ...

function mouseMoved()
{
    secureStorageComb_0 = 0;
    secureStorageComb_1 = 0;
    console.log("mouseMoved", mouseX, mouseY);
}

function mouseDragged()
{
    secureStorageComb_1 = (secureStorageComb_1 + 54);
    console.log("mouseDragged", mouseX, mouseY);
}

function mousePressed()
{
    secureStorageComb_0 =(secureStorageComb_0 + 14);
    secureStorageComb_1 =(secureStorageComb_1 + 34);
    console.log("mousePressed");
}

function mouseReleased()
{
    secureStorageComb_0 = (secureStorageComb_0 + 6);
    secureStorageComb_1 = (secureStorageComb_1 + 77);
    console.log("mouseReleased");
}

function keyPressed()
{
    secureStorageComb_0 = (secureStorageComb_0 + 15); 
    console.log("keyPressed", key);
}

function keyReleased()
{
    secureStorageComb_0 = (secureStorageComb_0 + 41);
    secureStorageComb_1 = (secureStorageComb_1 + 86);
    console.log("keyReleased", key);
}

///////////////DO NOT CHANGE CODE BELOW THIS POINT///////////////////

function draw()
{
    //Draw the safe door
    background(70);
    noStroke();
    fill(29,110,6);
    rect(26,26,width-52,width-52);

    //Draw the combination dial
    push();
    translate(200,height/2);
    drawDial(200, secureStorageComb_0, 43);
    pop();

    //Draw the lever
    push();
    translate(width - 125,256);
    drawLever(secureStorageComb_1);
    pop();
}

function drawDial(diameter,num,maxNum)
{
    //the combination lock

    var r = diameter * 0.5;
    var p = r * 0.6;

    stroke(0);
    fill(255,255,200);
    ellipse(0,0,diameter,diameter);
    fill(100);
    noStroke();
    ellipse(0,0,diameter*0.66,diameter*0.66);
    fill(150,0,0);
    triangle(
    -p * 0.4,-r-p,
    p * 0.4,-r-p,
    0,-r-p/5
    );

    noStroke();

    push();
    var inc = 360/maxNum;

    rotate(radians(-num * inc));
    for(var i = 0; i < maxNum; i++)
    {
    push();
    rotate(radians(i * inc));
    stroke(0);
    line(0,-r*0.66,0,-(r-10));
    noStroke();
    fill(0);
    text(i,0,-(r-10));
    pop();
    }

    pop();
}

function drawLever(rot)
{
    push();
    rotate(radians(-rot))
    stroke(0);
    fill(100);
    rect(-10,0,20,100);
    ellipse(0,0,50,50);
    ellipse(0,100,35,35);
    pop();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/p5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried to insert my code in the space designated for it, but still the sketch does not makes open the safe

I'm not sure what you mean by opening the safe. I believe the assignment is just giving you a motivating story and not speaking literally. Your code doesn't have a safe in it, so nothing is going to unlock.

One thing that sticks out to me is that you're doing things like this:

```
secureStorageComb_0 = (secureStorageComb_0 + 6);
```

This line of code **adds** 6 to `secureStorageComb_0`, but the instructions say to set the variable equal to 6. Notice that the instructions specifically said you should only use the `=` operator, not the `+` operator.

But anyway, I don't think there's meant to be a safe that unlocks, other than in the assignment description.

Comment: Thank you so very much. I really appreciate your help.

Before, I coded it with = operator as you point. It still did not open the safe but it did successfully move the buttons. Are you telling me that according to how you see the assignment, all it wanted me to do was code to move buttons??

Comment: @Mag Yeah that's my understanding. I don't see any code for a safe or opening anything. So unless your teacher has you include some extra code (maybe in another `<src>` tag?), then it sounds like the assignment is just about getting the buttons to move. I'd double-check with your teacher though.

Comment: I feel like such a noob. After your post, I submitted my code into the assessor and it was right. So thanks you I have realised it was a metaphorical instruction as part of the story. Too bad I spent four hours before I posted here and you helped me... :D

Again, thank you. I'm a first time poster, and you've made me confident I can find help here. Saved my day.

Comment: @Mag You're very welcome, and don't worry- it happens to all of us!